# Spark Sql data from org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((Any, Any), Iterable[org.apache.spark.sql.Row])]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I have `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((Any, Any), Iterable[org.apache.spark.sql.Row])]` data,
how to print data or get data?

I have code like:

```
val sessionsDF = Seq(("day1","user1","session1", 100.0),
  ("day1","user1","session2",200.0),
  ("day2","user1","session3",300.0),
  ("day2","user1","session4",400.0),
  ("day2","user1","session4",99.0)
).toDF("day","userId","sessionId","purchaseTotal").toDF()

val groupByData=sessionsDF.groupBy(x=>(x.get(0),x.get(1))
val filterData=groupByData.filter(x=>x._1._1=="day1").map(x=>x._2)
```

The above code is returning `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((Any, Any), Iterable[org.apache.spark.sql.Row])]`

Comment: First - this code does not compile, perhaps you meant `sessionsDF.rdd.groupBy(x=>(x.get(0),x.get(1))`? And what is `data`?

Comment: sorry typing mistake,edited it.

Comment: Tzach pointed out that your code doesn't compile. is it running in yours. and I don't think you can do `.groupBy(x=>(x.get(0),x.get(1))` on a dataframe unless its a dataset

Comment: question still unclear: (1) still doesn't compile; (2) after fixing compilation , `filterData` has type `RDD[Iterable[Row]] ` and not `RDD[((Any, Any), Iterable[Row])] `

Answer (score 1):

In your first step, you have `.toDF()` extra. Correct one is as below

```
val sessionsDF = Seq(("day1","user1","session1", 100.0),
  ("day1","user1","session2",200.0),
  ("day2","user1","session3",300.0),
  ("day2","user1","session4",400.0),
  ("day2","user1","session4",99.0)
).toDF("day","userId","sessionId","purchaseTotal")
```

In your second step, you missed `.rdd` so the actual second step is

```
val groupByData=sessionsDF.rdd.groupBy(x=>(x.get(0),x.get(1)))
```

which has *dataType* as you mentioned in the question as

```
scala> groupByData
res12: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((Any, Any), Iterable[org.apache.spark.sql.Row])] = ShuffledRDD[9] at groupBy at <console>:25
```

to view the `groupByData` `rdd` you can simply use `foreach` as

```
groupByData.foreach(println)
```

which would give you

```
((day1,user1),CompactBuffer([day1,user1,session1,100.0], [day1,user1,session2,200.0]))
((day2,user1),CompactBuffer([day2,user1,session3,300.0], [day2,user1,session4,400.0], [day2,user1,session4,99.0]))
```

Now your third step is filtering data which has `day1` as value for `day column` in your `dataframe`. And you are taking only the values of the *grouped* `rdd` data.

```
val filterData=groupByData.filter(x=>x._1._1=="day1").map(x=>x._2)
```

the returned *dataType* for this step is

```
scala> filterData
res13: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Iterable[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]] = MapPartitionsRDD[11] at map at <console>:27
```

You can use `foreach` as above to view the data as

```
filterData.foreach(println)
```

which would give you

```
CompactBuffer([day1,user1,session1,100.0], [day1,user1,session2,200.0])
```

You can see that the returned *dataType* is an `RDD[Iterable[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]]` so you can print each values using a `map` as

```
filterData.map(x => x.map(y => println(y(0), y(1), y(2), y(3)))).collect
```

which would give you

```
(day1,user1,session1,100.0)
(day1,user1,session2,200.0)
```

if you do only

```
filterData.map(x => x.map(y => println(y(0), y(3)))).collect
```

you would get

```
(day1,100.0)
(day1,200.0)
```

I hope the answer is helpful